# Unrecognized Arguments error while running a python code

Tags: python, parsing, arguments

```
    import os
import subprocess
import re
import argparse

apps_dir = None
inputs_dir = None
outputs_dir = None

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Runs Arthur routing test cases.')
parser.add_argument('test_dir', type=str, help='Path to root folder where bin and test_cases folders should exist.')

def run_test(app, test):
    app_exe = os.path.join(apps_dir, app)
    app_ver = re.search(r'ArthurCLI-(d/).exe', app).group(1)
    inputs = os.path.join(inputs_dir, test, app_ver)
    outputs = os.path.join(outputs_dir, test, app_ver)

    if not os.path.exists(inputs):
        return

    if not os.path.exists(outputs):
        os.makedirs(outputs)

    for i in os.listdir(inputs):
        base_fname = os.path.splitext(i)[0]
        i_fname = os.path.join(inputs, i)
        i_file = open(i_fname)

        o_fname = os.path.join(outputs, '%s.out' % (base_fname))
        o_file = open(o_fname, 'w')

        print('%s < %s > %s\n' % (app_exe, i_fname, o_fname))
        p = subprocess.Popen(app_exe, stdin=i_file, stdout=o_file)
        p.wait(),
        o_file.flush()

        i_file.close()
        o_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()

    test_dir = os.path.normpath(args.test_dir)
    apps_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'bin')
    inputs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'test_cases')
    outputs_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'results')
    if not os.path.exists(outputs_dir):
        os.makedirs(outputs_dir)

    for app in os.listdir(apps_dir):
        for test in os.listdir(inputs_dir):
            run_test(app, test)

    print('[Done]')
```

when I am running this code it throws an error "Unrecognized Error", so I wanted to know where to pass the directory path to handle this error. it needs to have a path for test_dir to run this code, how do I handle it. I think the main error is in the main method.

Comment: What line is the error on? What is the command you are running?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] - this example will not run because there are no `import` statements for a start, and secondly you do not show how (or even if...) you initialised the `parser` object.

Comment: here is the complete code that i want to run

Comment: What does `print(args)` show after the parsing? In fact, how are you invoking this code from the command line?

Comment: And since there's a hint of Windows in the code, `foo.py \bar\wibble\baz.txt` is going to cause problems - try escaping the backslashes in file names or replacing them with forwardslashes.